# Sphalerons In Laymans Terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, weak-interaction

I’m a 3rd year physics undergrad and I’ve just finished my first particle physics course. I’m looking for an explanation (at my level) of what a sphaleron is? They were mentioned as an aside in one of my notes and I’m interested in learning more now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, systems can move from one potential minimum to another through thermal fluctuations. If the minima are separated by a high energy barrier, than the main factor that determines how quickly this happens is the peak energy $E$ of the barrier, since you need that much energy to climb across, which gets penalized by a Boltzmann factor of $e^{-E/k_B T}$.

This logic applies to, e.g. quantum molecules in chemical reactions, but it also applies to the states of entire quantum fields. There are distinct minima that the field can tunnel between. Sphalerons are the field configurations at the top of each barrier. We care about them because if we know what they are, then we can compute their energy, so we can compute the rate of tunneling. That in turn is interesting because this tunneling process can do unusual things such as produce baryons.

Comment: When you say fields can tunnel between distinct minima, is that a situation similar to how a false vacuum  could ‘fall further down’ to a true vacuum which is a global minimum rather than a local minimum.

Comment: @James Yes, but there's an important difference, which is that most of the time when people talk about false vacua, they're imagining a situation at _zero_ temperature. In that case, the tunneling is through quantum tunneling instead. The rate is set by some other quantity, called the Euclidean action, which you compute from field configurations called instantons.

Comment: @James But yes, it's true that all of these things are basically tunneling phenomena.

Comment: That’s amazing, thanks so much!